# Creating Custom Rules for .Net Analyzers

Tags: .net, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

We are switching to .Net Analyzers on our .Net 5 and 6 projects.  On previous projects we had dlls we wrote for some custom rules that we use.  I've looked around and can't find any information on how to write custom rules (only custom rulesets) for .Net Analyzers.  Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow after spending a long time looking, I overlooked the page at MS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix